# C# Load integers and display odd / even

Tags: c#

Hello wondering if there is an easier way to display odd / even numbers.
I know I could do a for loop and load a list.  Then I can write another for loop
to loop through the list and check if a value is odd / even:

```
for(i=0; i<100; i++)
 if(myList[i]%2==0) //even
    //do something
 else
    //odd do something
```

But is there any way to shorten this up just so that I can easily get a list of odd or even numbers.  Not homework just wondering.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Could you use some sort of lambdas:

```
//load a list, t, with 100 integers
List<int> t = Enumerable.Range(1, 100).ToList();

//find odd numbers
var oddNumbers = t.Where(num => num%2 != 0);

//find even numbers
var evenNumbers = t.Where(num => num%2 == 0);

//print odd numbers
foreach (int i in oddNumbers)
    Console.WriteLine(i);

//print even numbers
    foreach(int i in evenNumbers)
        Console.WriteLine(i);
```

The Enumerable just loads the list with 1-100, and then I simply snatch all odds / evens and then print them.  This all can be shortened to:

```
var e = Enumerable.Range(1, 100).Where(num => num%2==0); //for even numbers
var o = Enumerable.Range(1, 100).Where(num => num%2!=0); //for odd numbers
```

e,o have an implicit type var.  The compiler can determine its type so these two lines are equivalent to:

```
List<int> eo = Enumerable.Range(1, 100).ToList(); //must tell it its a list
```

Then to find the odds / evens directly to a list type:

```
List<int> o = eo.Where(num => num%2!=0).ToList();
List<int> e = eo.Where(num => num%2==0).ToList();
```

And to print it is listed in my initial code.

Comment: Your predicate for odd numbers contains a nasty bug. See if you can find it.  (Hint: you need more test cases.)

Comment: @Eric Lippert maybe num % 2==1 was a bad choice...as 2==1 returns false :).  Will edit...let me know if I am mistaken.

Comment: Good guess, correct fix, but no cigar because you did not actually diagnose the problem. Try your original code with a range that goes from -100 to +100.

Comment: @Eric you just changed the sign on your comment you originally had -100 to -10 which is not possible.

Comment: @Eric - -1 due to negative numbers, I'll admit it was a nice catch :).  Whoever invented negative numbers and imaginary numbers made life difficult :-p.  Best thing to use is != to avoid that.

Comment: Correct. Just to be clear for other readers: A%2 is -1 if A is a negative odd number. Therefore A%2==1 is not a test for "is odd", it is a test for "is both positive and odd". A%2!=0 is a test for "is odd".

Comment: Note that this is clearly defined in the specification in section 7.7.3: "The result of x % y is the value produced by x – (x / y) * y"  So try -3%2 -- that's (-3) - (-3 / 2) * 2, which is -3 - (-2) which is -1.

Comment: @Eric - thanks for the information, can't believe they have that in the spec too!

Comment: Its a good exercise and good taste of code here. Check this : https://github.com/garora/TDD-Katas/blob/master/TDD-Katas-project/TDD-Katas-project/OddEvenKata/OddEven.cs also an explanatory code

Answer (score 16):

The LINQ way... Odd and Even numbers between 1 and 100.

```
var even = Enumerable.Range(1,100).Where(i => i % 2 == 0);
var odd = Enumerable.Range(1,100).Where(i => i % 2 != 0);
```

Comment: It's more faster to replace i%2 with i&1 into your example

Comment: Lonli-Lokli but then it takes two head switches to understand whats going on.  Readability is more important for such an insignificant amount of savings.

Comment: @JonH Good point, but I think people should be encouraged to write things in a performant manner, provided they explain. eg: `// i & 1 == 0 is faster than i % 2 == 0`

Answer (score 3):

You can use LINQ to pull out just the odd or even, and then process:

```
var even = myList.Where(i => i%2==0);
foreach(var number in even)
     // do something
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var t = Enumerable.Range(1, 100).ToList();
var oddNumbers = t.Where(n => (n & 1) != 0).ToList();
var evenNumbers = t.Where(n => (n & 1) == 0).ToList();
```

Comment: How is this useful, when a 12 upvotes answer said this already 2 years ago?

Comment: I understand that you're working to unlock some features, perhaps try some new / unanswered questions as well :)

Answer (score 1):

One mistake here: you need to include `int` before `i=1;` so that `i` becomes a recognised integer.

```
for (int i = 1; i < 101; i++)
{
   if (i % 2 != 0)
   {
      //do something
   }
}
```

Or even:

```
for (int i = 1, i < 101, i+=2)
{
   //do something
}
```

Comment: The problem is not to choose the odd or even indices, it is to choose the odd or even elements of the list of integers.

Answer (score 0):

Populate your list according to these formulas

```
Odds[0->N] = 2*i+1
Evens[0->N] = 2*i
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only need half of the numbers, just generate half the numbers ( .. ; .. ; i = i + 2)

If you need all the numbers but want to avoid an additional loop, you can mark them or process them during the initial loop.

Or, during creation, make up to three lists/arrays - one for all numbers, another for odds, and the third for evens.

Is there a specific application?

Comment: The problem is not to look at the even indices, the problem is to look at the even elements.